# jqgrid saverow related help needed

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jqgrid

This is a grid im currently working on

```
var lastsel;

grid.jqGrid({
url:'grid_data_loader.php,
datatype: 'json',
mtype: 'POST',
colNames:['ID','Date Created','Subject','Status','Location','Action'],
colModel :[ 
  {name:'id', index:'id', align:'center', hidden:true},
  {name:'date'}, 
  {name:'subject'},
  {name:'status',align:'center'},
  {name:'location',editable: true, align:'center', edittype:"select",

editoptions: { 
               dataUrl: 'control.php',
               dataEvents: [
                  {  type: 'change',
                     fn: function(e) {
                        grid.saveRow(lastsel,true);

                     }
                  }
               ]
}     


  },
  {name:'action'}
],
rowNum:10,
rowList:[10,20,30],
autowidth: true,
height: "100%", 
pager: '#pager',
sortname: 'id',
viewrecords: true,
rownumbers: true,
sortorder: "asc",
editurl: "control.php?case=8",
onSelectRow: function(id){
  if(id && id!==lastsel){
    grid.jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel);
    grid.editRow(id,true);
    lastsel=id;
  }
}

});
```

everything works fine but i can't figure how to check the server response after row is saved

any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: This question helps me answer a question of my own on how to use saveRow after an edit. So thank you :) 
But could you please post your control.php file as well? It would really help me and others out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `aftersavefunc` and `errorfunc` parameters of [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow).